# Origin of the expression “Fundamental theorem of Algebra”

Tags: terminology, algebra

Who was the first person to use the expression “Fundamental theorem of Algebra”? It is well-known that Gauss called it “Fundamental theorem of algebraic equations”. Grattan-Guiness, in his *The Rainbow of Mathematics: A History of the Mathematical Sciences* claims that “The modern name, ‘the fundamental theorem of algebra’, seems to have come in late in the 19<sup>th</sup> century”. But who used it first?

Comment: Jeff Miller's [site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/f.html) describes the first use in English as: *Fundamental theorem of algebra appears in English in 1887 in “A New Method in Analytic Geometry” by William E. Story in American Journal of Mathematics: “...the fundamental theorem of algebra, briefly stated: every equation has a root.”*